# Edges not showing up in Autodesk.NPR Extension

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've created my 3D Viewer using apis of v7 Forge Autodesk Viewer. I am tying to show the edges of models but with below codes the edges is not showing up :

```
    viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.NPR');
    var ext = await viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.NPR');
    ext.setParameter("edges", true);
```

When I use : `ext.setParameter("style", "cel")` it works and even works for style: edging. I don't know what I am missing. And when I work with same model this extension works for 'style' but when I refresh the page the 'ext' object becomes null.

I tried Autodesk.NPR for v7 verison but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `edges` parameter can't be used on its own, in other words, the edges can only be displayed as part of one of the NPR styles like `edging`, `cel`, `graphite`, or `pencil`.

You could add the following piece of code to your application (right after the viewer itself is initialized) to make sure that the NPR style is always activated automatically:

```js
// initialize the viewer ...

const ext = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.NPR");
ext.setParameter("style", "graphite");
ext.setParameter("edges", true);
```